# SQL statements only hang when wrapped in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

my problem is odd. I have written a block of SQL statements, nothing tricky though, only things like temp table creation, select, delete, insert. All plain stuff.

When I run it, it is fast, just seconds. Now I try to put the block of code into a stored procedure, and exec the proc. Weird thing happens. The EXEC never return.

I checked sysprocesses table and can see my INSERT statement is taking huge CPU and never ends. The INSERT is not very big - 100,000 rows, but the table is not small (20 million rows).

So do you know what possible reason causes fast standalone query but hanging inside stored proc?

Comment: Maybe parameter sniffing. What does the stored procedure and the execution plan look like?

Comment: Can you post a example?

Comment: @Martin Smith, yes it is parameter sniffing! Thank you for the hint. I am SQL newbie and now I feel must learn more quickly.